# Using LaTeX font in R (Computer Modern)

Tags: fonts, r, computer-modern

I am looking for at way to plot graphs in R, using LaTeX fonts.

In the documentation for `pdfFonts` in R, it states that:

> There are also mappings for "ComputerModern", "ComputerModernItalic" and, as from R 3.1.0, "ArialMT" (Monotype Arial).

When using `pdf(file = outputFile, width=11.692, height=8.267, family = "ComputerModern")` I get the following error message:

```
Error in pdf(file = outputFile, width = 11.692, height = 8.267, family = "ComputerModern",  : 
  unknown family 'ComputerModern'
Execution halted
```

I am using `R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)`. How can I use LaTeX fonts in R? Preferable without installing extra libraries.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure that this is entirely on-topic for this site. It would probably be more appropriate on Stack Overflow. Nonetheless, there's a `fontcm` package that can be used with the `extrafont` package (see [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html)). I've never had much luck getting that to work. Instead, I've had luck installing [`cm-unicode`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/) and using it as "CMU Serif" with `extrafont`.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I tried your proposed solution, but ended up with probelms for my PDF Viewer. I have posted my solution below.

Comment: Did you also embed the fonts in your PDF? If they're not embedded in the PDF, then the viewer would just default to a certain font. `extrafont` provides the command `embed_fonts()` to allow you to do this, which is discussed in the link from my first comment. You can also use `CairoPDF()` from the `Cairo` package to embed fonts, which is something I've had more success with than using `extrafont`'s `embed_fonts()`. `tikzDevice` is a good solution, too, though!

Comment: `tikzDevice` and `knitr` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330486/11604

Comment: This does not work on R4.0 +

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The selected solution.

It seems to be imposible to do without installing an external library. I tried using `extrafont`, but then my default PDF Viewer did not have the font used.

I ended up using the library `tikzDevice`, which exposes the method/device `tikz`, acts exactly like the `pdf` device, but outputs `TikZ` code instead. This seems more powerful, since the font is then entirely dependent on my `LaTeX` setting and I can include arbitrary math symbols.

Below is the code I am using, which plots the running time of my algorithms with standard deviation error bars and writes the output to a `.tex`-file.

```
tikz(file = outputFile, width=11.692, height=8.267)
ggplot(tgc, aes(x=E, y=wall.time, colour=Algorithm)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=wall.time-se, ymax=wall.time+se), width=.1) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Number of edges (|E|)") +
  ylab("Wall time (secs)") +
  ggtitle(paste0("Running time with |V| = ", dt$X.V.[1])) +
  theme_bw()
endoffile <- dev.off()
```

Comment: With `options()` you can change the `tikzDefaultEngine` to `luatex` (or `xetex`), for example, and then you can add lines to the preamble of the output file with `getOption()` and `tikzLuatexPackages` (or `tikzXelatexPackages`) that would allow you to specify the font you want with `fontspec`. See §2.1 of the [`tikzDevice` manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/vignettes/tikzDevice.pdf).

Answer (score 16):

This is how I did it in Windows:

1. Install the `extrafont` package.
2. Install Latin Modern fonts, e.g. from http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman. Watch out, you need to install the **TTF version** of the font, `font_import()` can't handle OTF.
3. Import the fonts using `font_import()`.
4. Load the fonts using `loadfonts(device = "win")`. Use the `device = "Win"` parameter to make the preview in R Studio work.
5. Set the font family graphics parameter using `par(family = "LM Roman 10")`.
6. Plotting in R Studio now works and so does pdf export (see the pictures below).

This is the full code you need to use:

```
    # Run once
    install.packages("extrafont")
    library(extrafont)
    # Install **TTF** Latin Modern Roman fonts from www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman
    # Import the newly installed LModern fonts, change the pattern according to the 
    # filename of the lmodern ttf files in your fonts folder
    font_import(pattern = "lmodern*")


    # Run each time
    library(extrafont)
    loadfonts(device = "win")
    par(family = "LM Roman 10")
    x <- seq(1, 10, 1)
    y <- seq(1, 10, 1)
    plot(y ~ x, main="This plot uses LaTeX font!", ylab = expression(alpha))
```

R Studio preview:
[image: R Studio preview]

Exported pdf:
[image: PDF export]

Comment: On https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman I don't see an option to download TTF's?

Comment: me neither...has it been removed?

Comment: Yes, the GUST foundry stopped generating TTFs with version 1.010x in 2007. It might still be possible to compile them in FontForge from the sources.

Comment: There is, however, a TTF distribution of [Computer Modern Unicode](ftp://canopus.iacp.dvo.ru/pub/Font/cm_unicode/).

Comment: loadfonts(device='win') returns an error

Answer (score 3):

I also tried several times and found that one need to use `device=cairo_pdf` to save the pdf figure.
It looks like that (by the way, I used `ggplot2`):

```
library(extrafont)
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 10, 1), y = seq(1, 10, 1))
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme(text=element_text(family="LM Roman 10", size=20)) +
  ggtitle("This plot uses LaTeX font!")
ggsave("fig.pdf", width = 6, height = 4, device=cairo_pdf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Refering to @Augustin answer
fontsquirrel lets you download OTF files by default.
OTF and TTF files are nevertheless same fonts shapes but

from library(extrafont)
font_import(pattern = "lmodern*")   only installs TTF files.

To install TTF follow the following steps.

1. Open webpage https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman
2. Click "Webfont Kit", then check "TTF"
3. Click "DOWNLOAD @FONT-FACE KIT", download a zip file containing TTF version fonts.
4. Install "lmroman10-regular-webfont"

then use font_import(pattern = "lmodern*")