# Fonts in latex and R

Tags: fonts, koma-script, r, computer-modern, tikzdevice

This question could be linked to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283472/using-latex-font-in-r-computer-modern), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232296/how-to-change-font-of-labels-in-r-plot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890215/getting-r-plots-into-latex/35989420#35989420). However, I opened a new one because I tried two different options from the suggestions and getting different results.

The aim is to get consistent font in latex document (`scrbook`) when graphs/diagrams are plotted using R. I see two basic approaches.

1) Using `tikzDevice` and following piece of code

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz("rtikzFile.tex" )
plot(1,1,xlab="Real count")
dev.off()
```

this generates a `rtikzFile.tex` file which I include with the `main.tex` file. This works nicely. However, I have many contour, spatial plots, for which the tex file could be really really big. I heard from a colleague of mine that TeX also have a word limit for compilation (though it is a very high value but for a phd thesis with tikzDevice it could be achievable.)

Output --

[image]

2) Using `extrafont` in `R` and following piece of code

```
library(extrafont)
 loadfonts()
 pdf("extrafontR.pdf",family="CM Roman")
 plot(1,1,xlab="Real count") 
 dev.off()
```

I have installed the [`CM Roman`](https://github.com/wch/fontcm) fonts as instructed [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html).  Output --

[image]

Now, if I compare the results of the two approaches, the font looks different. I checked this with `Mac Preview` and `Acrobat Reader`. This looks completely wrong in default viewer of `TeXStudio` (less important). I am more concern for the fonts in pdf viewer. **I would like to get the same output as in approach 1) but using approach 2). This way, I will have more control on my figures and compile time for tex will be lesser.**

My questions are --

1. Am I using correct font and settings?
2. Is this to do with my pdf viewer?
   OR
3. Should I ask this ok SO instead?**

P.S. My knowledge about fonts is very limited.

Comment: I'm voting to close (or move) this question as off-topic because this question would fit much better at http://stackoverflow.com due to its broad scope.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I do not know much about R, but helped prepare a book that used R plots throughout back in 2012. The book is set in Kp-fonts and we wanted as much as we could in that font from R as well (all titles and legends were replaced via `psfrag` to get proper LaTeX formatting of those, but handling the numbers on axis was a bit too much for psfrag.

Here is more or less what I did at that time

(1) Copy all the appropriate `.pfb` and `.afm` files for Kp-fonts into the folder where I have the R files.

(2) Create `Kp-fonts.R` with this content:

```
KP <- Type1Font("KpFonts",
                      c("./jkpmn8a.afm", "./jkpbn8a.afm",
                        "./jkpmit8a.afm", "./jkpbit8a.afm",
                        "./jkpssmn8a.afm"),
                      encoding="default"
                      )
```

(3) start all R files via

```
source("Kp-fonts.R")

#pss
postscript(family = KP,file="name.eps",useKerning=FALSE)
#pse
```

The generated EPS is then available for `psfrag` later. The `useKerning` is vital for `psfrag` as R might otherwise apply kerning to the text and thus `example` is no longer `example` as a string in the EPS.

Comment: Thanks. By "R files" in (1), do you mean the R installation directory or R scripts? I have R scripts at many directories and sub-directories and copying it too many places is not nice (in my opinion).

Comment: @Amit I only had this single project where all the R files were in one folder. And as I mentioned I know almost nothing about R, so I do not know where to generally place R files in your setup so you can use them in several locations.

Comment: I will give this a shot and it it works, I will write back here or just add it to your answer.