# LaTeX Roman Latin 10 font for ggplot in R

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use the LaTeX font for ggplots in R. I searched the wep and tried everything around for example:

https://fulowa.medium.com/latex-font-in-a-ggplot-9120caaa5250

https://rstats-tips.net/2019/08/31/custom-fonts-in-ggplot2-and-latex/

[Using LaTeX font in R (Computer Modern)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283472/using-latex-font-in-r-computer-modern)

The **problem** I have is that font_import() cannot find the Latin Roman 10 font even though it is installed as a ttf in the corresponding C:\Windows\Fonts folder. Tried to restart, uninstall/install again but nothing works. Someone familiar with the problem and solved it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the font installed properly, can you choose it in the font selection in Microsoft Word for example?

Comment: Thanks Marijin for your fast respond. I tried it and it seems to work. I can find the font in Microsoft Word as LM Roman 10